# Any nonempty string - regular language

Tags: regular-language

I don't really see the difference in expressions here.

There's **any string at all** and then there's: **any nonempty string**

Alphabet **Σ**:

```
{a, b, c}
```

I understand that `(a+b+c)*` can be either `a, b, c`

But what difference does just another `(a+b+c)` make?

[image]

These answers are taken out of some lecture slides.

Can somebody please explain why we need another `(a+b+c)`?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you understand what is meant by an "empty string"?

Comment: I do, but I'm still not quite sure why we need two (a+b+c)

Answer (score 3):

Remember that the asterisk represents zero or more occurrences. So the first example can result in a blank string. However, the second string has to start with one of a, b or c, and then potentially zero or more other characters, so it will be at least one character in length.

Comment: Does the asterisk not interfere with both (being at the end?), and I presume an asterisk is like a loop? Thus having many occurrences if need be?

Comment: The asterisk only applies to the term immediately preceeding it. If it needs to apply to multiple terms they will be wrapped in brackets of some sort (which I believe you've seen in previous examples).

Answer (score 1):

A string can be empty if it is just "". This is a valid value for a string so it would be part of the category "any string at all."

Comment: I understand the first one but it's the second I don't quite understand. Why are we using two: (a+b+c) - can't we just use one?

Answer (score 1):

When you apply Kleen star clouser to any RE, it will produce empty string (length = 0) in the case of `(a+b+c)*`, so when `*` is replaced by 0, the result will be empty string. To get rid off that empty string here we placed (concat) `(a+b+c)` before `(a+b+c)*`, so that every string produced by `(a+b+c)*` is prefixed by either `a or b or c`, this way we are making sure that an empty string cannot be produced by this RE.